# how to connect Capacitor in audio circuit

Tags: capacitor, audio

I am making an audio amplifier circuit using TDA7297 which I got from an old tv circuit. At the input I have connected two capacitor in series with pin 4 and 12. Also two capacitors are connected to pin 4 and 12 to the ground as I figured out from the tv circuit. But when I connect an input there is only a buzzing sound. I want to know if the capacitors connected between input pins and ground are causing the problem as there are no such capacitors in the circuit shown in datasheet of IC.  [image]
The capacitor C3 and C4 has value of 2.2nF (222)

Comment: Seems like connecting it up as shown in the datasheet would be a reasonable starting point.

Comment: Does connecting capacitors to ground also grounding the signal?

Comment: Words are inadequate for circuits.  Post a schematic diagram of what you have built, and a link to the datasheet for the amplifier.

Comment: @innovativesahil: That depends on the frequency of the signal. As a *grossly* simplified view, a capacitor looks like an open circuit at low frequency, and a short circuit at high frequency (for some suitable definitions of "low" and "high").

Comment: Data sheet http://www.radiotechnika.hu/images/TDA7297.pdf

Comment: @JRE Info added. Are C3 and C4 causing any problem. Also C1 and C2 have value of .68uF as opposed to .22uF used in datasheet.I got them from the same tv circuit and they were connected at input. What is the effect of capacitors value in Audio circuit

Comment: I think rather than trying to duplicate the TV circuit, you should build it like the examples in the datasheet.

Comment: None of the examples in the datasheet have capacitors from the inputs to ground.

Comment: And also: when supplying more information, edit the original question, don't post it in the comments.

Comment: thanks everyone the circuit is working after removing C3 & C4. And the output is fine but with a little humm but thats ok